# Where is the access violation is my code?

Tags: c++, access-violation, primes

I'm getting an Access Violation when attempting to run this code which finds prime numbers in a bound.

```
int main () {
    cout << "Program initialized successfully. Please wait for the next message to appear." << endl << endl ;

    int Primes[51] ;
    int runner = 0 ;
    int chaser = 0 ;
    int bound = 0 ;
    int count = 0 ;

    cout << "Please enter the maximum boundary of the calculation : " ;

    cin >> bound ;

    cout << endl << "The number you've entered, " << bound << ", has been accepted. Please wait for the calculations." << endl ;

    if (runner <= bound ) {
        Primes[0] = 2;
        Primes[1] = 3;
        Primes[2] = 5;
        Primes[3] = 7;
        Primes[4] = 11;
        count = 4;

        for ( runner = 11 ; runner <= bound ; runner ++ ) {
            while ( runner % Primes[chaser] != 0 ) {
                for ( chaser = 0 ; Primes[chaser] != 0 ; chaser ++ ) {
                    if ( runner % Primes[chaser] == 0 ) {
                        count ++ ;
                        Primes[count] = runner;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int chaser_count;
        cout << "Here's the primes computer discovered : " << endl ;
        for ( chaser_count = 0 ; chaser_count <= count ; chaser_count ++ ) {
            cout << Primes[chaser_count] << endl ;
        }
        cout << "There is " << count << " primes discovered." << endl ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program runs fine until to the line of calculation : if(runner <= bound)

I got a Access Violation.

I Kind of know what an Access Violation is, but I don't know what raised it.

edit:

I got 2 answers now stating that I may have something like Primes[50] going on, but I seriously doubt so, because I get the error immediately after I specify the bound, 12.

Thanks for the guy who de-comment this.

I'm using Dev-C++.

I found the place where the error was raised. Thanks for anyone who commented and answered for me. It is an logical error that I didn't found that leads to a Prime[51].

Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: The debugger tells you where the crash happens. Which IDE / compiler / debugger are you using?

Comment: Having read your description of yourself in your account, I'd really encourage you to set yourself yourself a challenge of working out how to use the debugger on whatever software development environment you are using. That way, when you get crashes like this, you can step through the code line by line, to find out what's going on. I think you'd find it a really useful skill, and you'd learn a lot. What C++ environment are you using?

Comment: @sbi Out of interest, why did you delete all the comments from the original code, but not explain why you did it?

Comment: @ClareMacrae: The commit comment reads "removed needless comments." They were cluttering the code more than they helped understanding it. What good is it for to comment a variable definition with "this defines a variable"? Maybe I could have retained some, but I was too lazy for that, and I thought better remove a few too many from this simple code rather than have them all.

Comment: Shane, you might want to learn to use a debugger to single-step through code.

Comment: @sbi You're right, I definitely forget to use single-step. Thank a lot

Comment: @ClareMacrae Maybe sbi is right that I shouldn't put too much comment in the code since it's useless to you guys who didn't need to know what the codes do but how it works. And as a respond to your suggestion, I will put IDE info in my profile. Thanks.

Comment: Shane, if you're a bit shy of using your IDE's debugger, or for some reason can't, there's one time-honoured debugging tradition that's never failed me yet - printf() hunting. The trick is to put a printf() at every single place in the code where you've just made a decision. This includes the line after any "for", "while", "if", "else", "switch", and "do" statements. Within the printf output every single variable that was relevant in making the decision, and any variable that's been affected by the decision. If you had followed this technique you would have cleared this mess up in no time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here :

`for ( chaser = 0 ; Primes[chaser] != 0 ; chaser ++ ) {`

you didn't initialize you `Primes` array with 0, so the loop can loop over and over and chaser can be bigger than 51 (the size of you Primes array) and then `Primes[something_bigger_than_50]` will raise an access violation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to prevent that from happening with a limit I set on in my brain, which is to make the bound really small when I am testing it. But it seems I have made an error in my code that leads to a infinity if loop in the code.